# Load script after the rest of the page without deferring it?

Tags: javascript

I have an image scroller that is blocking resources from loading until it has loaded.
I have tried deferring the script but it then doesnt want to work when its deferred.
What would be the simplest method for getting it to load after the rest of the page?
Ive looked at some jquery methods but its like reading chinese to me

Comment: `its like reading chinese to me`. Time to start learning the language, then.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {... //stuff happens here});` maybe?

Comment: Try using $.getScript(); function. Call this on DOM ready and its success callback try to call the image scroller functions you need. Try using these links http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/ and http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getscript.asp

Comment: @sideroxylon is that all i need to use?

Comment: From the jquery api doc: 'The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.'.  Give it a try and see.

Comment: It would be useful to understand why it doesn't work when deferred because all other methods of delaying it are likely to suffer similar consequences.

Comment: @sideroxylon Is it as simple as putting that piece of code you gave me on the page or is more required?

Comment: @jfriend00 i wouldnt know how to find that out. all i know is it works without the defer tag but not with.

Comment: @Techagesite I checked the below links and they are in English as well. So You wont have problem understanding those. Try to get that working with some efforts on your end. http://api.jquery.com/ready/ and http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp

Comment: @jfriend00 you can have a look at the page, maybe you can spot something http://www.techagesite.com/page-1work1112211.htm its not currently deferred

Comment: When I got to that web page, what am I looking for?  What script?  What problem that you're trying to fix?

Comment: In the document head theres a script <script src="js/dw_con_scroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and right before the closing body there is the script for the scroller

Comment: @Techagesite - Actually you have two separate script blocks that are using the scroller code, not just the one at the end.

Comment: unhold my question. Im getting answers from people who understand the question and making progress

Comment: How is the question unclear?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some various options:

1. Place the `<script>` tag right before the `</body>` tag.  This will allow the rest of the DOM to load before your script even starts to load.
2. Construct some code to dynamically load the script and don't run that code until either `$(document).ready()` fires or perhaps even `$(window).load()` fires depending upon how many resources you want to wait for before starting your script.  You can dynamically load the script in jQuery with `$.getScript()` or it's fairly simple to just dynamically insert a script tag too.
3. Troubleshoot your code to figure out why the `defer` attribute doesn't work because it's designed for situations like yours where you want other things to load first.  My guess this was because you added `defer` loading for the library, but didn't delay your own code that attempts to use the library thus that code didn't work when you deferred the loading of the library.

Some references on script loading:

[load and execute order of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts/8996894#8996894)

[Script Tag - async & defer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer/10808243#10808243)

[improving website performance by dynamically loading javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170495/improving-website-performance-by-dynamically-loading-javascript/13170508#13170508)

[pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701)

---

In looking at your actual page code, a reason why your script wouldn't work when you add `defer` to it is that you have code that depends on that script that can't be run until after the dynamic scroll code has been loaded.  In looking at your code, I see this block of code and one other block similar to it:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

if ( DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div.isSupported() ) {

    DYN_WEB.Event.domReady( function() {

        // arguments: id of scroll area div, id of content div
        var wndo = new DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div('wn', 'lyr1');
        // see info online at http://www.dyn-web.com/code/scrollers/continuous/documentation.php
        wndo.makeSmoothAuto( {axis:'h', bRepeat:true, repeatId:'rpt1', speed:100, bPauseResume:true} );

        var wndo2 = new DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div('wn2', 'lyr2');
        wndo2.makeSmoothAuto( {axis:'h', bRepeat:true, repeatId:'rpt2', speed:60, bPauseResume:true} );

    });
}

        </script>
```

Both of these have to be run AFTER the scroll library is loaded.  So, if you delay the loading of the scroll library, then this code has to be run after the library is loaded.

If you're moving the scroll library to right before `</body>`, then place these blocks of code right after it (without using the defer tag on any).

Comment: if i put it at the end of the document do i just insert it like this <script src="js/dw_con_scroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @Techagesite - Yes, you would move that to the end of the `<body>` section, but you would also have to move your DYN_WEB code that uses that library to be AFTER wherever you insert this script tag (see what I added to the end of my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});
</script>
```

or this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   if ( DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div.isSupported() ) {

DYN_WEB.Event.domReady( function() {

    // arguments: id of scroll area div, id of content div
    var wndo = new DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div('wn', 'lyr1');
    // see info online at http://www.dyn-web.com/code/scrollers/continuous/documentation.php
    wndo.makeSmoothAuto( {axis:'h', bRepeat:true, repeatId:'rpt1', speed:100, bPauseResume:true} );

    var wndo2 = new DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div('wn2', 'lyr2');
    wndo2.makeSmoothAuto( {axis:'h', bRepeat:true, repeatId:'rpt2', speed:60, bPauseResume:true} );

});
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where do i put that code?

Comment: You can add it to the body of your page, after the HTML

Comment: Ok is that code javascript?

Comment: jquery.  see edit to answer to ensure you have jquery loaded.

Comment: What's the difference between your two options?  And, aren't you missing `<script>` tags?  And, from the [jQuery doc for `.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/): `As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.`

Comment: Is this correct <script>$(window).bind("load", function() { // <script src="js/dw_con_scroller.js" type="text/javascript"> });</script> right after <body>

Comment: @jfriend00 yep, forgot the tags when I added the jquery load (added now).  My understanding of the difference is that the former fires on DOM ready, the latter once the page has fully loaded.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562609/should-i-use-window-load-or-document-ready-jquery)

Comment: Where do i put this? <script src="js/dw_con_scroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: The page head is probably the right spot.